# In Power Query, extract child list from nested list

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In a Power Query expression, I have this list which contains X child lists:

```
  aList = {
    {"a", each List.Sum([a]), type number}, 
    {"b", each List.Sum([b]), type number}, 
    {"c", each List.Sum([c]), type number}
  }
```

What I want is to extract the following list:

```
{"a", "b", "c"}
```

In other words, I want to list every first item of the child lists.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for?

```
let
    aList = {
        {"a", {"a1", "a2"}}, 
        {"b", {"b1", "b2"}}, 
        {"c", {"c1", "c2"}}
    },
    #"Zipped" = List.Zip(aList),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Zipped, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    Column1 = #"Converted to Table"{0}[Column1]
in
    Column1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple one-liner for extracting the first element of child lists:

```
#"a list" = List.Transform(#"a list of lists", each List.First(_))
```

for your example:

```
let
    aList = {
        {"a", each List.Sum([a]), type number}, 
        {"b", each List.Sum([b]), type number}, 
        {"c", each List.Sum([c]), type number}
    },
    firstElements = List.Transform(aList, each List.First(_))
in
    firstElements
```